# Javascript/jquery - Construct URL from entered form. Lookup and replace

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone help with the below code?

I am trying to pass a vip name from a user entered form;

Example
app-123.dc.domain.com

I have two DC's PAL/PFW I want it so that when a user enters either a PAL or DFW vip my url building part will add both app-123.PAL.domain.com & app123.PFW.domain.com

output example

New winow URL:
http://dashboardbuilder:3000/dashboard/db/omni-vip?var-vip1=app-123.PAL.domain.com&var-vip2=app123.PFW.domain.com

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('#open').click(function() {

    var fixedData1 = 'http://dashboardbuilder:3000/dashboard/db/omni-vip?var-vip1=';
    var fixedData2 = '&var-vip2=';      

    function test2() {
      var regex = /\.(pfw|pal)\./i;
      userEntry1 = $('#one').val(),
      pal = userEntry1.replace(regex, '.pal.');
      pfw = userEntry1.replace(regex, '.pfw.');
      return replaced2;
    }
    var newWindow = window.open(fixedData1 + pfw + fixedData2 + pal);

    newWindow.focus();
  });
});
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: you never call test2()

Comment: stylfe - it not working can you not see any issues with it?

Comment: Why do you define `test2()` inside the click event? And why don't you call it? The resulting poblem are the undefined variables `pfw` and `pfw`.